# Four items in bootstrap carousel Ng repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display four items in a slide. But how do I repeat it the main row, because it uses an active class for the active slide. This is how my HTML looks.

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="image in images"><a href="#"><img ng-src="{{image}}" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
```

And an example of the JSON.

```
$scope.images = [
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1",
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=2",
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3",
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=4",
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=5",
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=6",
"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=7",
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is divide the array in chunks...

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="image in images.slice(0,4)"><a href="#"><img ng-src="{{image}}" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="image in images.slice(5,9)"><a href="#"><img ng-src="{{image}}" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/sGX1Ft2ccf)

Comment: Thanks. But what about moving the 'active' class around, when the active div is supposed to be on display.

Comment: What do you mean? The item with the 4 columns is made active as you have a multi item carousel. See the demo.

Comment: Here <div class="item"> repeated two times but i have to fix that count dynamically how do i do that